# circumventing spring security

Tags: spring-security

In our app spring security uses ldap as a provider.

i am working on a change that will let you flip a flag in dev that will allow you to log in if your user/pass matches a value from database. the ldap server might be down and you can still log in.

What ive realized though is that some urls are secured with

```
@Secured( {"ROLE_USER","ROLE_MERCHANT"})
```

so i need to still have some dealings with spring security in order for my logins to work. How do i go about doing this?

Comment: Add all those roles to the user in the database?

Comment: no, but i can figure them out programmically. this requirement is somewhat of a hack, it will only be done in dev - i have a bit of room for writing crappy hacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure 2 providers: one LDAP provider and another DAO provider.

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="yourLdapAuthenticationProvider" />
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="yourDaoAuthenticationProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

If the LDAP fails, it will fall back to DAO authentication provider.

You will need to configure your own authentication filter to inject that flag into `yourDaoAuthenticationProvider` so that when the authentication falls back to `yourDaoAuthenticationProvider`, it can check whether to proceed with further authentication (say, in development) or ignore it (say, in production). So, in your `authenticationFilter`, override `setDetails()` to store the flag:-

**myAuthenticationFilter bean**

```
@Override
protected void setDetails(HttpServletRequest request, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest) {
    YourObject yourObject = new YourObject(request.getParameter("devAuthAgainstDAO"));
    authRequest.setDetails(yourObject);
}
```

With this, have your `yourDaoAuthenticationProvider` to check against this flag before proceeding with further authentication.

In the end, your configuration will look something like this:-

```
<sec:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <sec:logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp"/>
    <sec:intercept-url ... />

    <sec:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthenticationFilter"/>
</sec:http>

<bean id="myAuthenticationFilter" class="[YOUR_CUSTOM_AUTHENTICATION_FILTER]">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler"/>
</bean>

<bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="successHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/welcome.jsp"/>
    <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="failureHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp?login_error=1"/>
</bean>


<bean id="yourLdapAuthenticationProvider" ... />

<bean id="yourDaoAuthenticationProvider" ... />

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="yourLdapAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="yourDaoAuthenticationProvider"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```